# How would I add a x axis label in plt.subplots?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

I have a pretty complicated plt.subplots because I am trying to plot 29 different plots. Everything appears to be working, but I would like to add a label to my x-axis:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,30))
for i in range(int(len(fwf_tot_grnl.sum(dim=('X','Y')))/24)):

    # add a new subplot
    ax = plt.subplot(8, 4, i+1)

    # plot on the subplot
    ax.plot(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24],fwf_tot_grnl.sum(dim=('X','Y'))[i*24: (i+1)*24])

    # other formating
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(min(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),max(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),.25))

# want to add x label here!
    ax.set_xticklabels(['{:.2f}'.format(a) for a in np.arange(min(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),max(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),.25)], rotation=15)

    ax.grid()
    ax.set_title('FWF All Basins Monthly Data (2 year increments)')
    plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

I want to add an xlabel to this line:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(['{:.2f}'.format(a) for a in np.arange(min(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),max(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),.25)], rotation=15)
```

I tried just doing:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(['{:.2f}'.format(a) for a in np.arange(min(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),max(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),.25), 'Time'], rotation=15)
```

but I get this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-48-4e6a31743d8a>", line 13
    ax.set_xticklabels(['{:.2f}'.format(a) for a in np.arange(min(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),max(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),.25),'Time'], rotation=15)
                                                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I add a simple x label to my plt.subplots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ax.set_ylabel('FWF (km$^3$/yr)')
  ax.set_xlabel('Time')
```

I was looking at set x_ticks rather than xlabel! Just need to do set_ylabel/set_xlabel to define the x and y axis labels.